# XCode Beta 8.2 Installation

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently trying to find a way of how to get XCode Beta 8.2, but have not found one yet. I would like it if anyone could leave some suggestions on how to get it. I want to get 8.2 beta because I am trying to run my app on my iPhone which has ios 10.2 installed, which is not possible without having the correct XCode version corresponding with your current OS on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to download the beta version of Xcode 8.2 in order to build for iOS apps that are running the iOS 10.2 beta versions.

You can download it from https://developer.apple.com/download/